# MATLAB imshow/imagesc

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot/show an image with the certain parameters, but it doesn't show. Only the contour. Does anyone know how I can resolve my image to be shown the the parameters and contour? Thanks in advance

```
    imshow(image,'Border','tight','InitialMagnification',100)
    colormap(gray)
    hold on

    contour(phi,[0 0],'r')
```

Comment: Did you try to [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=contour+on+top+of+an+imagesc&rlz=1C1CHEU_enIL452IL452&aq=f&oq=contour+on+top+of+an+imagesc&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.4235&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Here's the [first search result](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56458)...

Comment: Yes, imagesc works well with the contour but I want a tight border and I have not found those arguments for imagesc but it doesn't work with imshow

Comment: Then the title of the question is misleading.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Take `im=peaks(256)' and use `im` both in the `contour` line and the `imshow` line and see.

Answer (score -1):

`imshow` only shows images that are UINT8 typed images. try `imshow(uint8(image))` and make sure that the values of the image range from 0 to 255 (scale it if needed).

If you need to scale, do

```
mI = min(min(image));
mA = max(max(image));
image = 255*(image-mI)/(mA-mI);
imshow(image);
```